# handling uploaded pictures with different dimensions

Tags: php, gd

I want to able to allow users to upload pictures.  Using the GD library I will create/store three different size images for a gallery and displaying the product.  The problem is scaling the dimensions for people who have uploaded different sized images.  For example, a 4000 x 3000 image will scale to what I want 240 x 180, however I notice that some users have pictures with different dimensions that will not scale to this, e.g. 3008 x 2000 and 3837 x 2551.

Can someone please guide me to the best way to handle these different image dimensions so they can be scaled to a common size.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set a final dimension, e.g: 300x300 Pixels

Then you divide both factors by the original dimensions, e.g

```
factor1=300/4000 <- Width
factor2=300/3000 <- Heigth
```

Now you scale the image by the smaller factor.
You should now have an image which is either 300 Pixels height or width. Now you cut everything greater than the final dimensions. Finished!

Hope that helps

Comment: functions you should look at are: imagecreatetruecolor, imagecopyresampled and imagecopy

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for such a function :

```
function resizePreservingAspectRatio($img, $targetWidth, $targetHeight)
{
    $srcWidth = imagesx($img);
    $srcHeight = imagesy($img);

    // Determine new width / height preserving aspect ratio
    $srcRatio = $srcWidth / $srcHeight;
    $targetRatio = $targetWidth / $targetHeight;
    if (($srcWidth <= $targetWidth) && ($srcHeight <= $targetHeight))
    {
        $imgTargetWidth = $srcWidth;
        $imgTargetHeight = $srcHeight;
    }
    else if ($targetRatio > $srcRatio)
    {
        $imgTargetWidth = (int) ($targetHeight * $srcRatio);
        $imgTargetHeight = $targetHeight;
    }
    else
    {
        $imgTargetWidth = $targetWidth;
        $imgTargetHeight = (int) ($targetWidth / $srcRatio);
    }

    // Creating new image with desired size
    $targetImg = imagecreatetruecolor($targetWidth, $targetHeight);

    // Add transparency if your reduced image does not fit with the new size
    $targetTransparent = imagecolorallocate($targetImg, 255, 0, 255);
    imagefill($targetImg, 0, 0, $targetTransparent);
    imagecolortransparent($targetImg, $targetTransparent);

    // Copies image, centered to the new one (if it does not fit to it)
    imagecopyresampled(
       $targetImg, $img, ($targetWidth - $imgTargetWidth) / 2, // centered
       ($targetHeight - $imgTargetHeight) / 2, // centered
       0, 0, $imgTargetWidth, $imgTargetHeight, $srcWidth, $srcHeight
    );

    return $targetImg;
}
```

Usage example :

```
$gd = imagecreatefromjpeg("images/image5.jpg");
$resized = resizePreservingAspectRatio($gd, 100, 100);
header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($resized);
```

This transform such an image :

[image]

To that one :

[image]